# How Loop more efficiently?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I got a situation relate to Looping.

Issue is that I want to check if EmployeeID in one range doesn't exist in another range copy and paste it into second range.

Please look at my code. Actually code was run successfully, but something goes wrong. Also I would like ask that how can I make this code more efficient to run Loop with high speed. Actually I tried to use arrays for it but don't know it is proper enough or not?

Thanks in advance!

```
Option Explicit

Sub UniqueWorkerCodeLoop()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j  As Integer
Dim DB As Worksheet:            Set DB = Worksheets("DB")
Dim Report As Worksheet:        Set Report = Worksheets("Report")
Dim Lrow1 As Long:              Lrow1 = DB.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim Lrow2 As Long:              Lrow2 = Report.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim DBTbl As ListObject:        Set DBTbl = DB.ListObjects("Table1")
Dim ReportTbl3 As ListObject:   Set ReportTbl3 = Report.ListObjects("Table3")
Dim DBArray As Variant:         DBArray = DB.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Value
Dim ReportArray As Variant:     ReportArray = Report.ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(DBArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(ReportArray, 1)
        If DBArray(i, 1) <> ReportArray(j, 1) Then
            DB.Range("A" & i + 3).Copy
            Report.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are trying to compare just 1 column from `DBArray` with 1 column `ReportArray` you can use 1 loop with `Application.Match` instead of 2 `For` loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
for i = 1 to ubound(DBArray)
    if application.iferror(application.match(DBArray(i,1),ReportArray,0),0)=0 then Report.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = DBArray(i,1)
next i
```

You've already found the value in the array, so just append that to the report sheet rather than copy/paste (i used your line and removed the pastespecial; i have not tested code)

---

**Edit1:**

Going to try and break down the information to ensure we're pulling appropriate information:

```
Dim i as long, lrs as long, lrd as long, sarr as variant, darr as variant
with sheets("DB")
    lrs = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'last row source
    sarr = .range(.cells(1,1),.cells(lrs,1)).value 'source array
end with
with sheets("Report")
    lrd = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'last row destination
    darr = .range(.cells(1,1),.cells(lrd,1)).value 'destination array
    for i = lbound(sarr) to ubound(sarr)
        if application.isna(application.match(sarr(i,1),darr,0)) then
            lrd = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'last row destination
            .cells(lrd+1,1).value = sarr(i,1)
        end if
    next i
end with
```

note that this code uses the rows/columns from sheet DB and Report.

Also note that your last row representations in your example code do not have fully qualified ranges (e.g., *sheets("report").Rows.Count*), which could be part  of your issue.  If the activesheet (what's showing) has no rows, then your rows.count is showing that as the base range.

Comment: . @ShaiRado didn't mean to steal your thunder!  had the same thought (match for 1-dimension, vlookup for multi-dimension), and posted as i added the .value rather than copy/paste

Comment: Thanks for the code. But currently the same problem is continued. In DBArray I have EmployeeID and this array dynamic. ReportArray EmployeeID column is empty. When I run the code for the first time unique EmployeeID was transfered into ReportArray. But if I run the same code again, the code bring same EployeeIDs into ReportArray. I couldn't solve it.

Comment: @Khazar is your data displayed in a standard excel spreadsheet, which supports column references, etc.?  You are using "Table" references, rather than a range such as *Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(lastrow,1))*, so maybe that is part of the issue?  I can't tell what makes up your table.  Intrinsically, the concept provided should fit the bill:  using the match() function to determine if a value is within a range; when an error occurs (aka a value is not found), you append that value to be matched to the end of the search range.  The search range can be any row/column count.

Comment: @Khazar updated post and also noticed you have some qualification issues in your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. your edited code works properly. I am grateful to you.